# Custom controller action to specific path in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, routing

how to redirect the custom controller path to specific store name

http://testurl.com/testmodule/index/testview/id/123/

to

http://testurl.com/testname

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code in your controller to set the redirect to your custom URL.

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
// or
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
```

**Edit:**

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('block_class')->setTemplate('template_file_path'));
// Do your process
$this->renderLayout();
```

> Reference: [Can you set a template for every action within a controller?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/214305/can-you-set-a-template-for-every-action-within-a-controller)

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: thanks it is redirecting but page is not loading with that id

Comment: Have you tried $this->_redirect($url); in your controller? 
Also Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirct($url);

Comment: no actually i am doing in controller like http://testurl.com/testmodule/index/testview/id/123/ in test view funtion i am setting a template and loading page with current url id parameter

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check.

Comment: ok i will check this and update you thanks

Comment: have you tried it @Raghu?

Comment: yes i have tried this, along with this i have added Router concept, this is working well now, thanks

Comment: Good to hear! Is my answer is acceptable or need modification?

Comment: no for my scenario this is ok

Answer (score 1):

In the controller action you need to write this line
to redirect with current parameter (redirect inside your domain, not to an external website)

```
$this->_redirect('testname/index/index', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
```